# Working with Customized Links in PHP

Tags: php

Please how can I extract a link such as this in PHP in order to redirect to the users page

```
www.donals.com/june
```

How do i get the june here.

Thanks

Comment: I have tried this 
$Link = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

But does not seems to be the perfect approach

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049).

Comment: U r looking for url segmemts chk my solution

Comment: Thanks. I do not know how to accept here but i find @Script47 answer Useful

Comment: @Lander, you cannot accept here as these are comments. Only answers can be accepted as answers, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parse_url function and than you can use explode() function for getting url segments

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

$segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);

print_r($segments);
```